# Avoid clicking twice to begin editing boolean (checkbox) cell in Backgrid

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

We are using Backgrid and have discovered that to begin editing a "boolean" (checkbox) cell in Backgrid, you must click twice: the first click is ignored and does not toggle the state of the checkbox.  Ideally we would get to the root of what is causing this behavior (e.g. is preventDefault being called) and solve it there, but I at first I tried a different approach with the following extension of BooleanCell's enterEditMode method which seemed like a logical place since it was upon entering edit mode that the checkbox click was being ignored.

Problem is my attempt also toggles the state of the previously edited checkbox.  Here is the code.

```
var BooleanCell = Backgrid.BooleanCell.extend({
    /*
    * see https://github.com/wyuenho/backgrid/issues/557
    */
    enterEditMode: function () {
        Backgrid.BooleanCell.prototype.enterEditMode.apply(this, arguments);
        var checkbox = this.$('input');
        checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Upon closer inspection there is something happening on blur of the previous checkbox causing it to be toggled first.  I logged $this.('input') and it correctly returns one element.  I think I need to get to the root cause instead of applying a bandage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
var BooleanCell = Backgrid.BooleanCell.extend({
    editor: Backgrid.BooleanCellEditor.extend({
        render: function () {
            var model = this.model;
            var columnName = this.column.get("name");
            var val = this.formatter.fromRaw(model.get(columnName), model);

            /*
             * Toggle checked property since a click is what triggered enterEditMode
            */
            this.$el.prop("checked", !val);
            model.set(columnName, !val);

            return this;
        }
    })
});
```

This is because the render method gets called by Backgrid.BooleanCell's enterEditMode method on click, and said method destroys and re-creates the checkbox as follows but in so doing loses the checked state (after the click) of the original "non-edit-mode" checkbox

```
  this.$el.empty();
  this.$el.append(this.currentEditor.$el);
  this.currentEditor.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach:

```
var OneClickBooleanCell = Backgrid.BooleanCell.extend({
  events: {
    'change input': function(e) {
      this.model.set(this.column.get('name'), e.target.checked);
    },
  },
});
```

This bypasses the CellEditor mechanism entirely and just reacts to the input event on the checkbox by updating the model.